# Data Parameter in Excel not working with Access Query Connection

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a connection to an Access DB query within Excel.  The field in the Access query is an expression turning a field into a proper date.  The problem that I'm having in Excel lies within passing the parameter from a cell containing the date that I want the query to run for.  The results are either completely wrong or result in nothing.  I have tried modifying the parameter cell to just about everything to no avail.  I have tried the edit query option under view connection and when prompted to put in the value for the parameter, it actually returns the data I want.  I would thing that this would be exactly the same parameter it would be grabbing from the formatted cell?

I have attached my connection's SQL command text below. And also an image with more detail and screenshots.

**This is the command text from Excel containing my Where clause:**

```
SELECT Query1.SETYPE, Query1.`SEORD#`, Query1.ORBILL, Query1.ORCUST, Query1.ORLDAT, 
  Query1.ORCONS, Query1.SESEV, Query1.CMTYPE, Query1.CMTEXT, Query1.ORDDATfix
FROM `C:\USERS\DRED\DESKTOP\ServiceFailures.accdb`.Query1 Query1
WHERE Query1.ORDDATfix =?
```

[image: Screenshots of Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Query1.SETYPE, Query1.`SEORD#`, Query1.ORBILL, Query1.ORCUST, Query1.ORLDAT, Query1.ORCONS, Query1.SESEV, Query1.CMTYPE, Query1.CMTEXT, Query1.ORDDATfix
FROM `C:\USERS\DRED\DESKTOP\ServiceFailures.accdb`.Query1 Query1
WHERE (Query1.ORDDATfix>=?)
```

Apparently putting the clause in parenthesis fixed the problem.